# How to fix Invalid character in identifier syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm a beginner in python and this is my first time using stackoverflow so please dont get angry if you find my question stupid thank you. in my code when it gets to the line l*‪0.00000062137119 for some reason i get the error Invalid character in identifier.can anyone please explain why. Thank you

```
l=eval(input("Enter a length: "))
print("inches(1), yards(2), miles(3), millimeters(4), centimeters(5), meters(6),kilometers(7)")
c=eval(input("Type a number to pick the unit your length is in:  "))<br/>
c-=1
n=eval(input("Type a number to pick the unit you want to convert to:  "))<br/>
con=[[l,l*0.027778,l * 0.000016,l * 25.4,l * 2.54,l * 0.0254,l * 0.000025],
 [l * 36,l,l * 0.000568,l * 914.4,l * 91.44,l * 0.9144,l * 0.000914],
 [l * 63360,l * 1760,l,l * 1609344,l * 160934.4,l * 1609.344,l * 1.609344],
 [l * 0.03937,l * 0.001094,l * ‪0.00000062137119‬,l,l * ‪0.1‬,l *‪ 0.001‬,l *‪ 0.000001‬],
 [l * ‪0.393701‬,l *‪ 0.010936‬,l * ‪0.000006‬,l * ‪10‬,l,l *‪ 0.01‬,l *‪ 0.00001‬],
 [l *‪ 39.37008‬,l *‪ 1.093613‬,l * ‪0.000621‬,l * ‪1000‬,l *‪ 100‬,l,l *‪ 0.001‬],
 [l *‪ 39370.08‬,l *‪ 1093.613‬,l *‪ 0.621371‬,l *‪ 1000000‬,l *‪ 100000‬,l *‪ 1000‬,l]]
print(con[c][n-1])
```

Comment: There's a U+202C character after `0.00000062137119`, try deleting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some weird invalid characters that weren't visible. Had to remove them one by one. Now its working.

Try this:

```
l=eval(input("Enter a length: "))
print("inches(1), yards(2), miles(3), millimeters(4), centimeters(5), 
meters(6),kilometers(7)")
c=eval(input("Type a number to pick the unit your length is in:  "))
c-=1
n=eval(input("Type a number to pick the unit you want to convert to:  "))
con=[[l,l*0.027778,l * 0.000016,l * 25.4,l * 2.54,l * 0.0254,l * 0.000025],
[l * 36,l,l * 0.000568,l * 914.4,l * 91.44,l * 0.9144,l * 0.000914],
[l * 63360,l * 1760,l,l * 1609344,l * 160934.4,l * 1609.344,l * 1.609344],
[l * 0.03937,l * 0.001094,l * 0.00000062137119 ,l,l * 0.1,l * 0.001,l * 0.000001],
[l * 0.393701,l * 0.010936,l * 0.000006,l * 10,l,l * 0.01,l* 0.00001],
[l * 39.37008,l * 1.093613,l * 0.000621,l * 1000,l*100,l,l* 0.001],
[l*39370.08,l * 1093.613,l*0.621371,l* 1000000,l* 100000,l * 1000,l]]
print(con[c][n-1])
```